# setting the start position of the edge from node in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

How do I set the position of the edge from the node i.e. the edge should origin only from that location from the node(e.g. top,center,bottom,etc).Sometimes node labels and the edges of some nodes are overlaping each other. If it is possible to set the edge origin, able to set the label to specific position, so that overlapping of edge with node labels will not happen.
Is it posible to set the edge origin?
Thanks !

Comment: I am hoping to find a solution too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a point of discussion.  For feature requests, please use the issue tracker:

See https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/783